# Array update in scala (an equivalent to NumPy broadcast assignment)

Tags: python, arrays, scala, numpy, variable-assignment

I'm learning Scala and right now I'm translating a piece of code from Python to Scala.

I've got two functions roughly like that:

```
def inner_function(arr):
    scratch = np.zeros(arr.shape)

    do_sth(arr, scratch)            # modifies scratch, doesn't modify arr
    do_sth_else(arr, scratch)       # as above

    arr[...] = scratch              # here's the broadcast assignment

def outer_function():
    arr = np.zeros((height, width))

    for _ in range(its):
        inner_function(arr)

    # do other things...
```

Everything translates well, except the `arr[...] = scratch` part. The closest equivalent I know of would be something like `for (x <- 0 until width) for (y <- 0 until height) arr(y)(x) = scratch(y)(x)`, but it looks ugly and nowhere near optimal.

So, I've made a workaround, moving the assignment to the outer function and using a mutable reference:

```
def innerFunction(arr : Array[Int]) : Array[Int] =
{
    val scratch = Array.fill[Int](height, width)(0)

    do_sth(arr, scratch)
    do_sth_else(arr, scratch)

    return scratch
}

def outerFunction() =
{
    var arr = Array.fill[Int](height, width)(0)

    for (_ <- 0 until its)
        arr = innerFunction(arr)

    // do other things...
}
```

It works, however, I still wonder if there is a way to write it in a way closer to the original code. (Without an explicit loop over all the indices.)

Does there exist a method, perhaps, intended to replace the whole contents of one array with elements of another array?

Comment: Why? You have to understand, from a Scala engineer's perspective, this is painful to answer. You've taken a function with a side effect and removed that side effect and made it purely functional. That's great! I was hoping your question would be about how to remove the mutable variable from outerFunction, but instead you want to go backwards?!

Comment: Tangentially, I've also spent several hours dabbling with another part of the code, replacing imperative code and scratch arrays with functional code and map+reduce and then it turned out it only made my code twice as slow…

Either something with my setup is horribly wrong or just more functional doesn't necessarily mean better.

(FWIW: the whole thing runs in under two seconds on a two-core notebook, so I doubt there is terrible room for parallelization.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scratch.copyToArray(arr)
```

Note that it doesn't copy the inner arrays, so if your `do_sth` and `do_sth_else` do something like `scratch(i) = arr(j)`, it won't work as desired. For that case you do need a loop, but it can be much simpler:

```
for (i <- 0 until height) scratch(i).copyToArray(arr(i))
```

However, your second solution is simply better. It removes unneeded extra work (copying the array) *and* it removes unneeded side effects <s>(including the problem in the previous paragraph!)</s> (edit: this is wrong; e.g. if you do `scratch(0) = arr(0); scratch(1) = arr(0)` I think your Python code will end up with different arrays with same contents in `arr(0)` and `arr(1)` in the next step, but the Scala code will have two references to the same array instead). You could remove the `var` as well:

```
def outerFunction() = 
  (0 until its).foldLeft(Array.fill(height, width)(0)) { (arr, _) => innerFunction(arr) }
```

or

```
def outerFunction() = 
  Function.chain(Stream.fill(its)(innerFunction _)).apply(Array.fill(height, width)(0))
```

Comment: I don't think `copyToArray` would be a deep enough copy.

Comment: Or rather, I don't think it's as deep as the copy in the NumPy code. It might be deep enough anyway.

Comment: I've considered it and thought it would be (and removed while working on the answer), but actually it does depend on what `do_sth` does. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, I've been thinking about it too, but what I came up with was more like `Iterator.iterate(arr)(innerFunction).drop(its).next`…

Comment: Yes, that's even better, really.

Comment: Oops: I think there is a case where just returning `scratch` gives a different result after all, see the edit. Unless I am misunderstanding Python's behavior, which is quite possible.